# How to have .git folders ignored by Eclipse projects

Tags: git, eclipse

Whenever I use eclipse on a folder with a .git folder, the .git folder is included in project wide searches and it is displayed in the Navigator view. Is there some way to:

1. Make sure that .git folders are not displayed in the Navigator view?
2. Make sure that .git folders are ignored in project wide searches?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Following the SO question "[How can I make Eclipse file search not include svn directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41934/how-can-i-make-eclipse-file-search-not-include-svn-directories)":

> With Helios, choose `Project -> Properties -> Resource -> Resource Filters` and then add an "`exclude`" filter for type "Folder" with name ".git":

[image]

Comment: +1 for freehand ellipses. Oh, and because it's a really useful answer.

Comment: IMO `All children (recursive)` checkbox should be checked also because `.git` folder has subfolders and Eclipse refreshes them when refreshing workspace. This takes extra time to refresh workspace.